# tailwind css change color of button on focus

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

i have two buttons, blue and red.

i want to set when red button is clicked/focused blue button should also turn red.

how can i achieve it using tailwind css.

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button class="focus:bg-red-700 bg-red-400 font-bold px-4 py-4 rounded-lg">
RED
</button>

<button class=" bg-blue-400 font-bold px-4 py-4 rounded-lg">
BLUE
</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tailwind don't has the css [**combinators**](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#combinators). Guess, you have two way to achieve this.

1. Create an extra css file and add this line

```css
button.bg-red-400:focus ~ button.bg-blue-400 {
  background-color: rgba(185, 28, 28, 1);
}
```

```css
button.bg-red-400:focus~button.bg-blue-400 {
  background-color: rgba(185, 28, 28, 1);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<button class="focus:bg-red-700 bg-red-400 font-bold px-4 py-4 rounded-lg">RED</button>

<button class="bg-blue-400 font-bold px-4 py-4 rounded-lg">BLUE</button>
```

2. You can create your own custom class with **@Variants** [documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#variants), but not with a link from CDN.

> Before using the CDN build, please note that many of the features that make Tailwind CSS great are not available without incorporating Tailwind into your build process. [documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation)

3. Solution with javascript

```js
  // Select all elements with `bg-blue-400` class
  const blueBox = document.querySelectorAll('.bg-blue-400');

  const changeColor = ev => {
    // Define button in the DOM
    const button = ev.target.closest('button');
    // Check, if the button was clicked
    if (button) {
      // Chenge color in the DIVs
      for (const box of blueBox) {
        box.classList.add('bg-red-400');
        box.classList.remove('bg-blue-400');
      }
      return;
    }
    // If clicked outside, the color will switch back
    for (const box of blueBox) {
      box.classList.add('bg-blue-400');
      box.classList.remove('bg-red-400');
    }
  };
  document.addEventListener('click', changeColor);
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div>
  <button class="one bg-red-400 font-bold px-4 py-4 rounded-lg">RED</button>
  <div class="bg-blue-400 font-bold px-4 py-4 rounded-lg">BLUE</div>
</div>

<div class="two bg-blue-400 font-bold px-4 py-4 rounded-lg">APPLY COLOR HERE</div>
```

Comment: Thankyou, can you please make this work?
https://play.tailwindcss.com/yUx94y6ww4

Comment: For this case you need to use javascript, because css can't to handle parent DOM element. I updated the snippet to see, how it would look.